# Accepting an ERC20 Token as Payment

Tags: solidity, contract-development, tokens, erc-20

Assuming I have deployed my ERC20 token, and the supply has been dispersed, is there any method of creating a separate contract that accepts that ERC20 token as payment and has user fields that send particular information to the contract?

Kind of like a contract that takes the token along with some information.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to receive ERC20 tokens onto a new contract along with data, you can create the new contract using ERC 223 token standard. [Read here](https://github.com/Dexaran/ERC23-tokens) (Dont be confused about the nomenclature, its ERC223 and not ERC23)

When you transfer the tokens, you can also send data in the function

```
transfer(address to, uint value, bytes data)
```

And since ERC223 is backward compatible with ERC20, there will be no breaking in contract.

A sample function can be as

```
function transferToContract(address _to, uint _value, bytes _data) private returns (bool success) {
    if (balanceOf(msg.sender) < _value) throw;
    balances[msg.sender] = safeSub(balanceOf(msg.sender), _value);
    balances[_to] = safeAdd(balanceOf(_to), _value);
    ContractReceiver reciever = ContractReceiver(_to);
    reciever.tokenFallback(msg.sender, _value, _data);
    Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value, _data);
    StateChanged(true,"Transfer to contract successful");
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's 3 approaches you could use:

1. In your first contract (contract A), you could add code that upon a transfer to an approved contract (B), you could make a delegate call to contract (B) to do something, and you could pass any information you have from contract A.
2. You could make a dApp that listens for the Transfer event on contract A, and then makes a transaction request to contract B to do something.
3. You could do similar to #2 except listen for the Approved event on A and then call the transfer on A yourself to ensure you transfer the token(s) to any address you want and also make a call to B to do whatever functionality you want there also.

Answer (score 0):

**I do not know.**

I've tried answering similar question on the similar site: https://delegatecall.com/questions/smart-contract-accepting-tokens-instead-of-ether-as-payment-4ca5abce-0037-4bd6-a1ae-26ef1658bd0e#i-was-thinking-about-accepting-dai-stablecoin-pegged-to-1-but-i--b8087a40-5a59-4f7a-a1a5-a7c7d1048b86

What I would do *(six months ago couldn't deploy my own ERC20 or ICO)* is to legacy web application running `web3.js` and listeting to `Transfer` event *(part of ERC20 standard)* and triggering some action in the desired smart contract...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/31190)

Comment: Suggested an alternative. It does provide answer to the question. "Accepting an ERC20 Token as Payment" - or actually... Yeah, I should read the body of the question.